# Text Inside of span, is not positioned correctly

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem getting the Circle text to the correct position. Specifically its vertical position. It is supposed to be centered both vertically and horizontally. And that must change.

I'm trying to get a button in the middle of the page. The two other divs will be filled in later.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: grey; position: static;height: 80px">
 <div style="width: 45%; height: 80px; background-color: #123456; float: left;"></div>
 <div style="width: 10%; height: 80px;float: left; background-color: blue; text-align: center">
  <span style=" background-color: green; font-size: 70px; cursor:pointer; display: inherit; height: 80px" >&#9863;</span>
 </div>
 <div style="width: 45%; height: 80px; background-color: #123456; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

It's likely an easy fix. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the line-height property to make adjustments to vertical alignment in this situation. See snippet below.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: grey; position: static;height: 80px">
 <div style="width: 45%; height: 80px; background-color: #123456; float: left;"></div>
 <div style="width: 10%; height: 80px;float: left; background-color: blue; text-align: center">
  <span style="line-height:1.2; background-color: green; font-size: 70px; cursor:pointer; display: inherit; height: 80px" >&#9863;</span>
 </div>
 <div style="width: 45%; height: 80px; background-color: #123456; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```